# Strange behaviour of BitmapData loaded from memory (PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapdata

The method for editing Bitmap using BitmapData and Lock and UnlockBits [taken from the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to work very differently on Bitmaps with  with different sizes. It only does this on PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb and changing it seems to fix it, but I'd like to know what's going on.

Here's the method for reference:

```
private void LockUnlockBitsExample(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        // Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
        for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
            rgbValues[counter] = 255;

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Draw the modified image.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150);
    }
```

It works just fine for Bitmap(200, 200) or Bitmap(200,250). But when it's used on Bitmap(50, 50) or most of the other sizes it goes completely crazy...

- The rgbValues array has unexpected length of 7600. (The expected length would be Width * Height * Bytes per pixel = 50 * 50 * 3 = 7500)
- This causes it to throw IndexOutOfRange Exception in most cases
- I tried to change the value added to the counter but none seems to work

```
for (int counter = 10; counter + 10 < rgbValues.Length; counter += n)
    rgbValues[counter] = 255;
//Doesn't work for any number put for n from 2 to 10
//I also limited it from beginning and end just to try
//if it's not changing some crucial value in the bytes
//(I know it's a nonsense but I tried)
```

- If 3 is put for n (referring to the code above) it yields a picture with 1st row red, 2nd blue, 3rd green, repeat
- If 1 is put there it actually makes the whole picture white

Can someone please explain why is this happening? And how can this be fixed? (besides changing the format)

**Note:** I'm not keen on this format but I'd like to know what's actually going on.

Comment: The stride is always a multiple of 4.  50x3 is not divisible by 4, it gets rounded up to 152.  So it is 152 x 50 = 7600 bytes.  Your *bytes* value is wrong, you forgot about the number of bytes needed per pixel.  Never ask for bmp.PixelFormat, your code always *really* cares about the exact pixel format.

Comment: Like @HansPassant suggests, you should probably read up a bit on what Image Stride is. A decent resource is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx .